# Gradle task "assmebleDebug" stuck on Invalidating cache

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

When i run my code using `flutter run -v` so its verbose and then i can see the log if it gets stuck
and currently its been stuck for 2 hours on this  :

```
[+154386 ms] Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\rafee\OneDrive\Desktop\GIT REPOS\csy\android\.gradle\7.4\checksums\md5-checksums.bin
[        ] Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\rafee\OneDrive\Desktop\GIT REPOS\csy\android\.gradle\7.4\checksums\sha256-checksums.bin    
[        ] Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\rafee\OneDrive\Desktop\GIT REPOS\csy\android\.gradle\7.4\checksums\sha1-checksums.bin      
[        ] Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\rafee\OneDrive\Desktop\GIT REPOS\csy\android\.gradle\7.4\checksums\sha512-checksums.bin    
[        ] Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\rafee\.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin
```

i have researched and no luck

running my flutter code on my android phone using usb debugging